# about og:title tag

Tags: facebook-like, meta-tags

No error is returned in Facebook debug tool.
Nevertheless, Like button doesn't work.

It must be problem with "og:title"tag.

In the case of  the following type of og:title, what is the problem?
( ○ is double-byte character)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="○○○○○○&nbsp;○○○○○○○&nbsp;○○○○○○&nbsp;○○○○○○○○○○○○&nbsp;○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○" />
```

Is "&nbsp"  problem?

Thank you In advance.

Comment: I meant to please post all of the markup (including the <html> tag) relevant to the Open Graph property and the code where your Like Button code is implemented. A jsFiddle would be extremely helpful too. Otherwise, it's impossible to determine if you have a character encoding issue, JavaScript crash, etc.

Comment: I'm really sorry for not replying sooner.
These are all of the markup relevant to the OGP tag.
Because of the use in a business website, I cannot post the exact copy of them.


<meta property="og:title" content="xxxxxx&nbsp;xxxxxx&nbsp;xxxxxx&nbsp;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&nbsp;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.gif" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html" />
<meta property="og:description" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

Comment: And the code of like button.

<li><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxx%2Fxxxxxxx%2Fxxxxxxx%2Fxxxxxxx.html&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=70&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:70px; *width: 76px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true" ></iframe></li>

Comment: I suspect your problem is not the `&nbsp` but more likely the multibyte characters. Does your page use a multibyte encoding? If not, then they might be throwing off the parser. Your iframe link appears to work, so I'm not sure why your Like button is dependent on the <og:/> tags.

Comment: Thank you for your replying.
I'll check and sort my tag sitations and I'll not disturb you any more for this time.
Thank you for your kindness.